# Not possible to install add-on for ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-select

I am trying to test the [ember-select-2](https://github.com/istefo/ember-select-2) component. It is advertised as very easy to set-up. According to the [readme](https://github.com/istefo/ember-select-2#including-select2-in-your-project):

```
# install addon from npm repository
$ npm install ember-select-2
# install dependencies
$ ember g ember-select-2
```

Installing the add-on works:

```
» npm install ember-select-2
```

But installing the dependency fails:

```
» ember g ember-select-2
version: 0.1.2
Unknown blueprint: ember-select-2
```

The only thing I have been able to find is that ember-select-2 is an *extraneous* npm package (whatever that means)

```
» npm list ember-select-2
test13@0.0.0 .../test13
└── ember-select-2@1.0.1  extraneous
```

This is my ember-cli installatioon:

```
» ember --version
version: 0.1.2
node: 0.10.25
npm: 2.1.3
```

How did I manage to break such a simple how-to?

### EDIT

I did some research: `extraneous` just means that it is not in the `package.json`. Adding `--save` solves that. So that is just a warning, and not the source of my problem.

Comment: Why are you installing it globally, npm install --save-dev ember-select-2, it should install dependencies by itself, after that you reference the file in your brocfile and you're good to go

Comment: I am not installing anything globally (the `g` for `ember g` means just `generate` I think). And I am only following the readme (nothing about the `brocfile` is specified)

Comment: oups, didn't notice the ember before it, with ember-cli the usual way to include outside libs is via the brocfile, brb gonna setup a test app and check out select-2

Comment: Hmm just ran a fresh install, followed the readme all is well

Comment: only difference between you and I was the npm install --save-dev ember-select-2

Comment: What version of ember-cli, npm, node are you using?

Comment: Cli: 0.1.2, npm : 1.4.28, node: 0.10.32

Comment: It seems the `--save` is indeed important. Without it the generate command does not find the blueprint. So, the solution is just to do `npm install ember-select-2 --save`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't set the save flag, the package isn't added to your package.json file as a dependency it is only downloaded into node_modules, you will either have to add it manually or use the flag and have it save you a step.

> --save: Package will appear in your dependencies.
>
> --save-dev: Package will appear in your devDependencies.
>
> --save-optional: Package will appear in your optionalDependencies.
>
> When using any of the above options to save dependencies to your
>   package.json, there is an additional, optional flag:
>
> --save-exact: Saved dependencies will be configured with an exact version rather than using npm's default semver range operator.

More info can be found in the [npm install](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html) docs.

Comment: This is indeed what is happening, but it is still unclear (for me), *why*  this is happening. Why should `ember-cli` refuse to use extraneous blueprints? Anyway, I am accepting your answer.

Comment: It's not about refusing, there's nothing to tell CLI that ember-select-2 is in the project, files might exist but there is no reference to them

Comment: Not completely convinced: what if it is in the package.json, but not really installed? Does ember-cli need to look in package.json *and* in bower_components? The blueprint is in bower_components, so there is where it must look, no matter what package.json says. And besides: why is the howto for ember-select-2 not even mentioning the `--save` flag? Is it not important for him, did he simply not notice that it was required, does this depend on the version of ember-cli (or node / npm / bower)? I have added issues to both ember-cli adn ember-select-2 regarding this issue.

Comment: Join me in [the chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63494/ember-js) for an explanation as to how ember-cli resolves packages and dependencies

Comment: If you don't have it installed it will fail, and it's your problem you didn't run npm install. I really don't see why you are fighting adding a dependency to the list of dependencies...

Comment: Thanks for your support. Just to clarify: I am not fighting it, it was just an unexpected problem. I *did* run `npm install`, but that was not enough (`--save` was needed). For me (and for the howto in the readme) running npm install was enough. Well: no! And besides, ember-cli does not inform about the problem: just a generic `Unknown blueprint`. For you, who knows that blueprints are searched in the package.json file, the problem is obvious. For me, who things that blueprints are searched in bower_components, it is not at all obvious. A clearer error message would have spared me this.

Answer (score 1):

As the maintainer of the package, I apologize for the inconvenience caused by the documentation.

I immediately fixed the command to include `--save-dev`, which seems to be the right way to install ember-cli addons.

Comment: Thanks! And this is not your fault (thanks for the package!), just me being an ember-cli beginner. The error is probably obvious to anyone already familiar with ember-cli. So, indirectly, you are helping me to learn ember-cli :) Thanks again!